# Asp.net:TreeView and Index was out of range

Tags: asp.net, treeview, treenode

I have a TreeView in my code (Tree1) and i am going to add  nodes in  **depth** , using my `CreatTree()` method. In Debug i understood that this line

(`Tree1.Nodes[i].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(i.ToString()))`) *does not lead to adding a node to Tree* so the error in the loop is:

**Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index**

**Can anybody tell me how can i add a Child to a certain Node?**

```
<asp:TreeView ID="Tree1" runat="server"  >  
</asp:TreeView>
```

The code behind is:

```
protected void CreateTree( )
        {

            Tree1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("0"));


            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                Tree1.Nodes[i].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(i.ToString()));;



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

can you tried with below code because at patent level you have added only 1 record and you tried to add new child node at four different parent node.

```
protected void CreateTree( )
        {

            Tree1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("0"));


            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                Tree1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(i.ToString()));;



        }
```

Comment: it just add a child to the *Root* ,but i want to add nodes in Depth
i mean i want to have childs for Node[1]

Comment: sorry I did not got your requirement. can you explain by image with edit question?

Comment: @ Naresh Pansuriya: i have already a node as my root in the loop i am going to add a child to a the last node

Answer (score 0):

This should do what I think you're looking for:

```
protected void CreateTree()
{
    Tree1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("0"));

    TreeNode currentNode = Tree1.Nodes[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        currentNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(i.ToString()));
        currentNode = currentNode.ChildNodes[0];
    }
}
```

You'll end up with 5 nodes, one under each other.